# If button pressed then change label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need help with tkinter.

My code:

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *


#Defs

#Start window
window = Tk()
window.geometry("700x250")

#Frames
F1 = Frame(window)
#F1.geometry("50x50")
#Buttons
B1 = Button(window, text = "Option 1")
B2 = Button(window, text = "Option 2")

#Placing of buttons
B1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=20)
B2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=20)

#Labels
L1 = Label(window, text = "Dungeon Game")

#Placing of labels
L1.pack()
F1.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=20)
```

I already know how to update code with `.configure(text="stuff here")`. But I need help on if button is pressed, update label. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code Button changes the label's text.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text = "Dungeon")
lbl.pack()

def some_callback_func():
    lbl['text'] = "This is the updated text."

#if btn is pressed then go to some_callback_func
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Update", command=some_callback_func)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an if statement without callbacks? I am trying to make a book that is like choose your own adventure. You click a button and the label is updated and the player chooses which one to choose. I can do this without tkinter. I just wanted to see if i could make it any nicer using a GUI.

Comment: @DarkestN2O You can create a list of button objects and then assign them to the same method with each having unique arguments and then that method would decide what to do, with an `if` statement. I can't think of a better way to achieve what you want.